# Backbone validate function not getting called

Tags: backbone.js

My validate function is not getting called in the code below:-

```
var Vehicle = Backbone.Model.extend({
    color: 'green',
    validate: function (attrs) {
        var validColors = ['white', 'red', 'blue', 'yellow'];
        var colorIsValid = function (attrs) {
            if (!attrs.color) return true;
            return _.contains(validColors, attrs.color);
        }
        if(!colorIsValid(attrs)) {
            return "color must be one of: " +validColors.join(",");
        }
    }
});

var car = new Vehicle();

car.on('error', function (model, error) {
    console.log(error);
});

console.log(car.get('color'));
car.set('color', 'muave');
```

Please see fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/vineet85/Fa8jr/5/

Can someone tell me why the validate function is not getting called?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Backbone.js `validate` is called automatically on `save` but not on `set`.

If you want validations to run when setting a value you will need to use the `validate` option. e.g.

```
car.set('color', 'muave', {validate: true});
```

See http://backbonejs.org/#Model-validate

The `error` event is triggered when an error occurs, typically on the server, when trying to save the object. See http://backbonejs.org/#Events-catalog

If you want to catch validation failures try handling the `invalid` event:

```
car.on('invalid', function (model, error) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? I think that your validate method is now be called. If you are wondering why no error is being written to the console its because the error event is not being triggered. See updated answer.

Comment: @Vineet, by saying that your fiddle still does not work, do you mean that error message ("*color must be one of: white,red,blue,yellow*") is not printed on the console log? I've noticed that in your Fiddle you still use event *error* instead of *invalid* as in Steve's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Seems need to write some extra code for to run the validate.
like below:

```
car.set('color', 'muave', {validate:true});
```